# Microphones for acoustic holography

Tags: audio, acoustic-holography, microphones

I'm considering building a hobby [acoustic holography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_holography) setup. I would need several (at least 12, I think) microphones to do this, but I have a limited budget. Does anyone have recommendations for microphones that are relatively cheap but still good enough to get decent resolution?

Comment: Do you have a specific budget that you can give as a guideline? Also, what are some _specific_ features you're looking for?

Comment: I have $100-200, and the reason I'm asking this question is I don't know what features I need.